# Can't update view from applicationWillEnterForeground when switched views in app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a two views(A and B) iOS app, each view has a button to switch from each other by
storyboard segues:modal.

The initial view is A, and it has some text labels. I put some codes in viewcontroller A to update the labels text of it, and when applicationWillEnterForeground I put code like:

```
 [_window.rootViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
```

to force update the view A's labels text.

Everything works fine unless I did switching views from A and B. If I switch to B, and switch back to A, and press home button to exit the app, then I launch the app, the view A's text label never update, or if I never do switch views, when I open the app from home screen, the view A get 
text labels updated well.

What's wrong with my app, how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should update the view in `applicationDidBecomeActive` rather than `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: Tried applicationDidBecomeActive but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `viewWillAppear`.